# Block Specific Website With Edge Router Lite

Tags: command-line, router

I am in need of a way to block a specific website on my edge router lite 3

I have squidguard enabled and I opened the CLI to run these commands

```
set service webproxy url-filtering squidgaurd
local-block-url https://www.crazygames.com/
redirect-url https://www.google.com/
```

however I get an error on the second command of `local-block-url: command not found`

What is the way using the CLI to block and redirect this site to google?

Comment: What makes you think your router supports that command or has this feature?

Comment: @Ramhound -> I was trying to follow the guide on there website on how to set-up such https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/218732788-EdgeMax-Create-a-Firewall-Rule-using-Deep-Packet-Inspection-DPI-